# Hive load data into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

i have data set having 100+ columns for each row. question is how can i load selected columns using hive into hdfs.

for example : col1 ,col2,col3...col50,col51....col99,col100 . I need to load only selected columns col1,col2,col34 and col99. 
Approach 1:
1. load all the columns 
2. and create view based on selected columns.
Approach 1 - cons- i need to load all the columns unnecessary and it will consume more memory in hdfs also i need to write big query for specifying the column 
. Any other best approach.

Comment: Internally hive doesn't do anything while loading data into a table, it just copies and pastes into a specific folder that's all. Your approach will be best as per my knowledge.

Comment: @vivek 26.. Thanks a lot.. any other hadoop eco system will help to load selected columns into hdfs.

Comment: Sqoop can help you here.

Comment: Will sqoop help to load flatfile or csv file ..

Comment: Yes, Sqoop supports.

Comment: You can refer to this link for more information:   https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_file_formats

Comment: Have any example references for how to implement ?

Comment: Long time back I did that, but currently, I don't have any implementation reference. Better you can create a staging table in hive every time and write a SQL statement to insert the required data into the target table like ETL kind of. I think that will be the better approach.

Comment: Hive doesn't "load" data into HDFS. Can you please add to your question what you've tried? Also Spark or Pig can directly read this data without defining a schema for the entire table

Answer (score 1):

`Hive` provides a tabular view on top of `HDFS` data. If your data is in `HDFS`, then you can create an external table on it to reference the existing data. You will need to put a schema over the data. This is a one time effort and then you can use all the features of `Hive` to explore and analyze the dataset. `Hive` supports views also.

**Illustration**

**Sample data file: data.csv**

```
1,col_1a,col1b
2,col_2a,col2b
3,col_3a,col3b
4,col_4a,col4b
5,col_5a,col5b
6,col_6a,col6b
7,col_7a,col7b
```

**Load and verify data in HDFS**

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /hive-data/mydata

hadoop fs -put data.csv /hive-data/mydata

hadoop fs -cat /hive-data/mydata/*
1,col_1a,col1b
2,col_2a,col2b
3,col_3a,col3b
4,col_4a,col4b
5,col_5a,col5b
6,col_6a,col6b
7,col_7a,col7b
```

**Create a Hive table on top of the HDFS data in `default` database**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.mydata
    (
      id int, 
      data_col1 string, 
      data_col2 string
    )
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    LOCATION 'hdfs:///hive-data/mydata';
```

**Query the Hive table**

```
select * from default.mydata;
mydata.id   mydata.data_col1    mydata.data_col2
1           col_1a              col1b
2           col_2a              col2b
3           col_3a              col3b
4           col_4a              col4b
5           col_5a              col5b
6           col_6a              col6b
7           col_7a              col7b
```